# Balanced Parenthesis checker problem without stack

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the parenthesis checker problem without stack after learning Python. My code does work on a lot of expressions but fails on plenty of them too. Especially when the same type of brackets appear concurrently.

```
exp = "([[]])"
#input("Enter the expression to evaluate: ")

def sumer(l):
    x=0
    for i in range(len(l)):
      x+=l[i]
    return x  

exp_num = list([])

for i in range(len(exp)):
   if exp[i]=="(":
        exp_num.append(1)
   if exp[i]==")":
        exp_num.append(-1)
   if exp[i]=="[":
        exp_num.append(2)
   if exp[i]=="]":
        exp_num.append(-2)
   if exp[i]=="{":
        exp_num.append(3)
   if exp[i]=="}":
        exp_num.append(-3)
del exp
for g, i in enumerate(exp_num):
    if i>0:
        try:
            op = exp_num.index(-i)
            sm = sumer(exp_num[g+1:op])
            if sm == 0:
                for x in range(g,op+1):
                    exp_num[x]= 0
        except ValueError:
            break
    else:
        continue      
if exp_num.count(0) == len(exp_num):
    print("The entered expression is valid !!")
else:
    print("The entered expression is not valid !!")
```

It works for above string but it will fail for `([[()]])`

So far what I am doing it is:

Step 1:  Give different type of braces a number, positive for opening and negative to closing. For example, '(' = 1 and ')' = -1. Finally, convert the input expression to a list of numbers in the same order.

Step 2: Start scanning the list and if a positive number(opening bracket) is found then find its corresponding negative(closing bracket). Find the sum of the numbers between these two.

Step 3: If the sum is 0 then simply replace all the processed items in the list with 0 and keep repeating.

In the end, if the list becomes with all items as zeroes then the expression is valid else the expression is not valid.

Comment: So 'without stack' would mean without functions and without intermediate variables?

Comment: If it fails on a few cases, it doesn't work. You are solving a *different problem*.

Comment: No. These kind of problems generally solve using a stack to keep track of the opening and closing of braces. Nothing to do with fucntions and intermediate variables, we can use them.

Comment: It appears that your code would "match" `(((` with `}` just as well as `)))` would, since the net sum is 0 in either case.

Comment: @chepner no i am solving the parenthesis problem.

Comment: You are *trying* to solve the parenthesis problem; you have not done so yet.

Comment: Without a stack, you are trying to solve the problem using a deterministic finite automaton. If you could do so, you would prove that this language is a regular language. However, you can use a [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) to prove that this is *not* a regular language, which implies that you need a stack to solve it.

Comment: mmmm, I have solved this one before using simple recursion, but i do not know if it uses the stack or not.

Comment: Recursion uses a stack: the Python runtime manages the stack for you.

Comment: Is this impossible then?

Comment: That's what I was thinking ! I have added what I am doing in the description.

Comment: Leveraging a stack is the simplest way to do this, and is efficient.  You can implement this a number of ways without it, where each is subjective to the programmer, but creates unneeded overhead in the amount of space and time.  The stack imo is the best solution.

Comment: You can simulate a stack on top of an integer (arbitrary precision) [Gödel style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering_for_sequences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to solve the parenthesis checker problem without stack after learning Python.

#### What if...

I could simply treat a list as a stack.

Let us initialise `expr` and `delimiters`:

```
expr = '[{[{<>}]}]'
delimiters = list()
```

And use `delimiters` as a stack:

```
# For each character in expression
for character in expr:
    # If it is an opening one
    if character in opening:
        # Add it's unique value to delimiters
        delimiters.append( opening.index(character) )
    # If it is a closing one
    if character in closing:
        # If there are opening delimiters and character matches the last opened one
        if delimiters and delimiters[-1] == closing.index(character):
            # It was valid, remove the opening delimiter
            del delimiters[-1]
        # Else, expression is invalid!
        else:
            break
```

where `opening` and `closing` are the matched pairs:

```
opening = '[({<'
closing = '])}>'
```

Last, if the list (previously called stack) is empty, the expression was valid:

```
print('Success!') if not delimiters else print('Invalid Expression!')
# same as:
# print('Success!') if delimiters == [] else print('Invalid Expression!')
```

Comment: There is no need to use bad language. The question is legitimate. It might require some deeper explanation, but it definitely doesn't deserve being insulted at.

Comment: @ibarrond Sorry, I meant it as a manner of speaking, and definitely did not mean to insult either the OP or the question. Corrected.

Comment: BTW, what is the meaning of ```if delimiters and delimiters[-1] == closing.index(character):``` ?

Comment: @SulemanElahi as mentioned in the comments, we first check if `delimiters` has any opening delimiters ie it is not empty. If it has, then we check if the last opened one is the correct pair for the current closing delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

The following implemention is done without using stack. This Python code is very easy to understand. Hence i'm not giving much explanation. From the output iteration, we can understand it easily.

```
exp = "{{{{{{[[[(((((()))))][)][][][][]]]}}}}}}"
length = len(exp)
print("Length of the string = ", length)
half = int(length / 2)
print("Max iteration is needed to check if it's a balanced string = ",half)
count = 1
print("Iteration ", count)
print(exp)
while(count != half ):
    count = count + 1
    print("Iteration ", count)
    if ('()' in exp ) or ( '{}' in exp) or ( '[]' in exp):
        exp = exp.replace('[]', '')
        exp = exp.replace('{}', '')
        exp = exp.replace('()', '')
        print(exp)
    else:
        print("Not a Balance string")
        break
    if len(exp) == 0 :
        print("Balance string")
        break
```

**Output with Unbalanced string: {{{{{{[[[(((((()))))][)][][][][]]]}}}}}}**

```
Length of the string =  40
Max iteration is needed to check if it's a balanced string =  20
Iteration  1
{{{{{{[[[(((((()))))][)][][][][]]]}}}}}}
Iteration  2
{{{{{{[[[((((())))][)]]]}}}}}}
Iteration  3
{{{{{{[[[(((()))][)]]]}}}}}}
Iteration  4
{{{{{{[[[((())][)]]]}}}}}}
Iteration  5
{{{{{{[[[(()][)]]]}}}}}}
Iteration  6
{{{{{{[[[(][)]]]}}}}}}
Iteration  7
Not a Balance string
```

**Output with balanced string: {{{{{{[[[(((((())))))][][][][]]]}}}}}}**

```
Length of the string =  38
Max iteration is needed to check if it's a balanced string =  19
Iteration  1
{{{{{{[[[(((((())))))][][][][]]]}}}}}}
Iteration  2
{{{{{{[[[((((()))))]]]}}}}}}
Iteration  3
{{{{{{[[[(((())))]]]}}}}}}
Iteration  4
{{{{{{[[[((()))]]]}}}}}}
Iteration  5
{{{{{{[[[(())]]]}}}}}}
Iteration  6
{{{{{{[[[()]]]}}}}}}
Iteration  7
{{{{{{[[[]]]}}}}}}
Iteration  8
{{{{{{[[]]}}}}}}
Iteration  9
{{{{{{[]}}}}}}
Iteration  10
{{{{{}}}}}
Iteration  11
{{{{}}}}
Iteration  12
{{{}}}
Iteration  13
{{}}
Iteration  14
{}
Iteration  15

Balance string
```

**Output with a perfect balaced string [([[[{{([{{[[[[]]]]}}])}}]]])]:**

```
Length of the string =  30
Max iteration is needed to check if it's a balanced string =  15
Iteration  1
[([[[{{([{{[[[[]]]]}}])}}]]])]
Iteration  2
[([[[{{([{{[[[]]]}}])}}]]])]
Iteration  3
[([[[{{([{{[[]]}}])}}]]])]
Iteration  4
[([[[{{([{{[]}}])}}]]])]
Iteration  5
[([[[{{([{}])}}]]])]
Iteration  6
[([[[{{([])}}]]])]
Iteration  7
[([[[{{}}]]])]
Iteration  8
[([[[{}]]])]
Iteration  9
[([[[]]])]
Iteration  10
[([[]])]
Iteration  11
[([])]
Iteration  12
[]
Iteration  13

Balance string
```

Answer (score -1):

in ur soln, in statement delimeter[-1] == closing.index(char)

u should correct it like

opening.index(delimeter[-1]) == closing.index(char)

Comment: Please, use code format for representing your codes.